# return difference of hours of 2 different days

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Well I need return the difference od 2 times

example 1:

```
var time1 = "1970-01-01 20:00:00";
var time2 = "1970-01-01 19:00:00";
```

with momentjs code:

```
var ms = moment(time2 ,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(time1 ,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
var d = moment.duration(ms);
var timeOfHourExtra = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");
```

the result is ok: `"1:00:00"`

But when is of the 2 differents days is the problem example:

```
var time1 = "1970-01-01 20:00:00"; //day1
var time2 = "1970-01-01 01:00:00"; //day2

//diference return -18:00:00
//should return 5:00:00
```

How can return the correct difference beetwen 2 days differents.

Comment: you'll need some dates on those times, because momentjs doesn't "know what you mean"

Comment: I use date ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")

Comment: yes, but your time `vars` have no date

Comment: Just add 1970-01-01 as default for example

Comment: `the result is ok` - with the code you posted, the result is `NaNInvalid date` ... and, changing to `HH:mm:ss` results in -1:00:00 ... so, not sure why you think your code is in any way valid

Comment: `//diference return -18:00:00` - actually returns *`-19:00:00`* because, well, `1 - 20 == -19` not `-18`

Comment: To put this in perspective. Say it's currently 2 PM, if I ask when 1 PM most people will say it was an hour ago and not 23 hours from now. Also in your current edit it ***shouldn't*** return 5:00:00 because you said it's the same day.

Comment: well now understand the problem I sum -18 + 24 and the result is the diference beetwen 2 dates if the result is less than "00:00:00" thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to compare the dates before getting the difference. Moment has built in functions for comparing dates: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/

You can also skip the conversion to milliseconds and then hours. `diff` accepts a second argument for the value you want it returned in. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

```
var time1 = "1970-01-01 20:00:00";
var time2 = "1970-01-02 01:00:00";
var timeOne = moment(time1);
var timeTwo = moment(time2);
var hourDiff = (timeOne.isBefore(timeTwo)) ?
    timeTwo.diff(timeOne, "hours") :
    timeOne.diff(timeTwo, "hours");
var timeOfHourExtra = hourDiff.toString() + ':00:00';
// 5:00:00
```